# Looking for example of Bazel genrule for calling shell script

Tags: android, shell, sh, bazel-rules

I have a shell script(.sh) for generating metadata of media files. I need to run the script while building the AOSP by using bazel genrule. Do any have similar examples or directions for me?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jin.crypt.sg/articles/bazel-in-5-minutes-genrule.html